# Publishing multiple buffers in mqttjs

Tags: node.js, mqtt, mqtt.js

So I want to send some bytes from a NodeJs script to my mosquitto server over mqtt. For this I am using the client library [MQTT.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js). To send raw data, the library supports Buffers (also Strings).

All of it works just fine until I try to publish multiple bytes (buffers) in a row. This will always result in publishing only the last buffer but multiple times. When I log the same buffers to the console instead of using mqttjs, I get my expected results (increment from 0xfa to 0xff). However, publishing normal Strings in a row works without trouble. The behaviour of this is inexplicable for me.

Not quite sure if this is a problem from mqttjs, or if I’m just dumb. Would appreciate a short explenation on what i'm doing wrong since i did not find any related issues.

```js
var buf = Buffer.from([0xfa]);

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('LED', function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      for (; buf[0] < 0xff; buf[0]++) {
        client.publish('LED', buf);
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Expected message (Result from logging to the console **instead** of publishing):

```
<Buffer fa>
<Buffer fb>
<Buffer fc>
<Buffer fd>
<Buffer fe>
```

Message that mosquitto receives:

```
<Buffer ff>
<Buffer ff>
<Buffer ff>
<Buffer ff>
<Buffer ff>
```

A funny discovery i made. If you put the publish before the loop (buf[0] = 0xfa):

```js
client.publish('LED', buf)
for (; buf[0] < 0xff; buf[0]++) {;}
```

The output is still:

```
<Buffer ff>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS is a pass by reference language, this means that the publish method is working on the same instance of the buffer object all the time. You are just passing a reference to the same structure to the publish method.

In this case the for loop is running quicker than the client can send the messages so by the time it gets round to actually packing the buffer's content into the message it has already been updated to be `0xff`

You will need to create new buffer objects (or clone the existing values) for each message you want to send.